# Eclipse 4 RCP - application does not have active window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to have some helper functions for manipulating UI.
I don't want to pass to them any parameters except what is necessary by my domain model (i don't want to pass EModelService, EPartService etc.)

**Question:** The problem is i am getting exception `application does not have active window.`
I found where the problem is.
 It happend because i am manipulating parts via `EPartService` accessed from the application context `IWorkbench.getApplication().getContext().get(EPartService.class)`.

***THIS IS IMPORTANT:*** Currently i am getting that exception when i am trying to modify my UI **AFTER** i read inputs from dialog. Pleas note that the error does not happened when i am trying to modify the UI just **BEFORE** i 
opened the dialog. Look at the code, i added some comments.

**NewFromDirectoryDialog.java**

```java
    package cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.handlers;

    import javax.inject.Named;

    import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
    import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
    import org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IServiceConstants;
    import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;
    import org.eclipse.jface.window.Window;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

    import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.BcModel;
    import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.resolvers.filesystem.FileSystemResolver;
    import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui.dialogs.NewFromDirectoryDialog;
    import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui.UI;

    public class NewFromDirectoryHandler {

        @Execute
        public void execute(MApplication application, EPartService partService, @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell) {
            FileSystemResolver fsr = new FileSystemResolver("/home/jara/git/cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc/bc/src",
                            "/home/jara/git/cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc/bc/bin");
                    BcModel.setResolver(fsr);
           // THIS CALL IS OK AND EVERYTHING WORKS
            UI.changeExplorerView("bc.partdescriptor.filesystemview", fsr);
            NewFromDirectoryDialog dialog = new NewFromDirectoryDialog(shell);
            dialog.create();
            if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {
                String sourceDir = dialog.getSourceDir();
                String classDir = dialog.getClassDir();
                FileSystemResolver fsr = new FileSystemResolver(classDir, sourceDir);
//THIS CALL LEADS TO EXCEPTION: application does not have active window             
UI.changeExplorerView("bc.partdescriptor.filesystemview", fsr);

            }
        }

    }
```

That `EPartService` from application context is based on `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl`
and not on `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl`
as `EPartService` instance you get when injected to `@PostConstruct` annotated method on `Part's` view.

**org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl (not entire source code)**

You can see that the error probably happened because at the time `ApplicationPartServiceImpl.createPart` is called in my `UI.changeExplorerView`, the Eclipse runtime does not know what window
is currently active.

```java
package org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench;

import java.util.Collection;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspective;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPlaceholder;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MInputPart;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.IPartListener;

public class ApplicationPartServiceImpl implements EPartService {

    private MApplication application;

    @Inject
    ApplicationPartServiceImpl(MApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    private EPartService getActiveWindowService() {
        IEclipseContext activeWindowContext = application.getContext().getActiveChild();
        if (activeWindowContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Application does not have an active window"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        EPartService activeWindowPartService = activeWindowContext.get(EPartService.class);
        if (activeWindowPartService == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Active window context is invalid"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        if (activeWindowPartService == this) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Application does not have an active window"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return activeWindowPartService;
    }

    @Override
    public MPart createPart(String id) {
        return getActiveWindowService().createPart(id);
    }

}
```

**LifeCycleManager.java (how i initialize the UI helper class)**

You can see i am injecting `IWorkbench` to my `UI` class.
`IWorkbench` allows me to access `MApplication`, so that is all i should 
need to modify app UI.

```java
package cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Optional;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.UIEventTopic;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.UIEvents;

import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui.UI;


public class LifeCycleManager {

    @Inject
    @Optional
    private void appCompleted(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) Object event, IWorkbench workbench) {
        ContextInjectionFactory.inject(UI.getDefault(), workbench.getApplication().getContext());
    }

}
```

**UI.java**

```java
package cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.MApplication;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPartStack;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService.PartState;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;

import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.BcModel;
import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.resolvers.ISourceAndClassResolver;

public class UI {

    public static final String PART_EXPLORER_ID = "bc.part.inspector";
    public static final String PART_EXPLORER_CONTAINER_ID = "bc.partstack.explorer_stack";
    public static final String PART_JAVA_SOURCE_VIEWER_ID = "bc.part.javasourceview";

    private static UI fInstance = new UI();

    @Inject
    private IWorkbench fWorkbench;

    private UI() {

    }

    public static void changeExplorerView(String partDescriptorId, ISourceAndClassResolver resolver) {

        EModelService modelService = fInstance.fWorkbench.getApplication().getContext().get(EModelService.class);
        EPartService partService = fInstance.fWorkbench.getApplication().getContext().get(EPartService.class);
        MApplication application = fInstance.fWorkbench.getApplication();

        MPart part = partService.createPart(partDescriptorId);
        MPart oldPart = partService.findPart(UI.PART_EXPLORER_ID);

        MPartStack partStack =  (MPartStack) modelService.find(UI.PART_EXPLORER_CONTAINER_ID, application);
        partStack.setVisible(true);

        if (oldPart != null) {
            partService.hidePart(oldPart);
        }

        part.setElementId(UI.PART_EXPLORER_ID);
        partStack.getChildren().add(part);

        BcModel.setResolver(resolver);

        partService.showPart(part, PartState.VISIBLE);

    }

    public static UI getDefault() {
        return fInstance;
    }

    public static void setJavaSourceLabel(String label, EPartService partService) {
        MPart part = partService.findPart(UI.PART_JAVA_SOURCE_VIEWER_ID);
        if (part != null) {
            part.setLabel(label);
        }
    }

    public static void setJavaSourceText(String source) {
        IDocument document = BcModel.getJavaDocument();
        if (document != null) {
            document.set(source);
        }
    }

}
```

I think the problem is when i open the dialog, the activeChild changes somehow to that new opened dialog and when i close it and try immediately change my UI, it does not work because the activeChild is still not properly setup back. Otherweise i don't know why it works fine just before i opened the dialog and doesn't work just after the dialog is closed.

Does anyone know if it is bug?

Comment: Once a dialog has been opened there is no active window until the code returns to the main UI thread loop. You should avoid using the Application Part Service and use the current part Part Service, the contents of these is not the same. You really need to pass the EPartService and the like to your `UI` code and not try to find it in that class.

Comment: well if it is really impossible, i don't have a choice :), thanks